# How to implement server side pagination in asp.net core Web API 2.1

Tags: pagination, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to implement server side pagination in a table. I need to know what code to write in the API controller get method and any other needed code.

I tried searching the internet but could not find any resource. And any resource that is close has poor explanation.

For an example of what I want please refer following link (Only look at the page numbers):

https://datatables.net/

Basically I want page numbers on the bottom and when you click on them the page changes.

According to my knowledge what should happen is when I send a HTTP request to the API with page number, page limit in the URL, it should return results with number of results equal to page limit and according to page numbers it should skip some results.
Also the resulting json should include number of pages so that i can populate the page numbers below the table.

It should be something like the following except the following is written in node and uses mongo db.

https://codeforgeek.com/2019/03/server-side-pagination-using-node-and-mongo/

I want to use .net core web API and SQL Server.

Current Code:

API Controller

```
 [Route("api/customer")]
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private readonly InventoryDatabaseContext _context;

    public CustomerController(InventoryDatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }

    GET: api/<controller>
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<CustomerTable>> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.CustomerTable.ToList();
    }
}
```

Model

```
 namespace API.Models
{
    public partial class CustomerTable
    {
        public static List<CustomerTable> customer = new List<CustomerTable>();
        [Key]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string CustomerTelephone { get; set; }
        public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }

    }
}
```

HTML and javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .selected {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" type="button">Add</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="button" id="editbtn" onclick="editItem(rowid)">Edit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" onclick="deleteItem(rowid)">Delete</button>

    <div>
        <table id="datatable" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Customer Name</th>
                    <th>Customer Telephone</th>
                    <th>Customer Address</th>
                    <th>Customer Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="cus"></tbody>
        </table>
        <ul id="pagination-demo" class="pagination-lg pull-right"></ul>
    </div>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="my-form">
                        <!--<input type="hidden" id="edit-id">-->
                        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="edit-id">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="edit-name" class="col-2 col-form-label">Customer Name</label>
                            <div class="col-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="edit-name" placeholder="Enter Customer Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="edit-telephone" class="col-2 col-form-label">Customer Telephone</label>
                            <div class="col-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="edit-telephone" placeholder="Enter Customer Telephone">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="edit-address" class="col-2 col-form-label">Customer Address</label>
                            <div class="col-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="edit-address" placeholder="Enter Customer Address">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="edit-email" class="col-2 col-form-label">Customer Email</label>
                            <div class="col-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="edit-email" placeholder="Enter Customer Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--<input type="submit" value="Edit">-->
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="editcustomer()">Edit</button>
                        <!--<a onclick="closeInput()" aria-label="Close">&#10006;</a>-->
                    </form>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The Modal2 -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal2">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="add-name" class="col-2 col-form-label">Customer Name</label>
                            <div class="col-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="add-name" placeholder="Enter Customer Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="add-telephone" class="col-2 col-form-label">Customer Telephone</label>
                            <div class="col-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="add-telephone" placeholder="Enter Customer Telephone">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="add-address" class="col-2 col-form-label">Customer Address</label>
                            <div class="col-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="add-address" placeholder="Enter Customer Address">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="add-email" class="col-2 col-form-label">Customer Email</label>
                            <div class="col-5">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="add-email" placeholder="Enter Customer Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-2">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="addCustomer()">Add</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="startDate" type="text" />


    <script src="~/AdminLTE/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/pagination/jquery.twbsPagination.js"></script>
    <script>

        var editor;



        let cus = null;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            getCustomer();
            getrow();
            highlightrow();
            $("button[id=editbtn]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#startDate").ejDatePicker();


            $('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination({
                totalPages: 5,
                // the current page that show on start
                startPage: 1,

                // maximum visible pages
                visiblePages: 5,

                initiateStartPageClick: true,

                // template for pagination links
                href: false,

                // variable name in href template for page number
                hrefVariable: '{{number}}',

                // Text labels
                first: 'First',
                prev: 'Previous',
                next: 'Next',
                last: 'Last',

                // carousel-style pagination
                loop: false,

                // callback function
                onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                    $('.page-active').removeClass('page-active');
                    $('#page' + page).addClass('page-active');
                },

                // pagination Classes
                paginationClass: 'pagination',
                nextClass: 'next',
                prevClass: 'prev',
                lastClass: 'last',
                firstClass: 'first',
                pageClass: 'page',
                activeClass: 'active',
                disabledClass: 'disabled'

            });



        });
        $('#datatable').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            $(this).addClass('info').siblings().removeClass('info');
            $("button[id=editbtn]").removeAttr("disabled");
        });
        function highlightrow() {

        }
        function getCustomer() {
            var json_url = 'https://localhost:44336/api/customer';
            $.ajax({
                url: json_url,
                type: 'GET',


                success: function (data) {
                    $('#cus').empty();
                    $.each(data, function (index, element) {

                        $('#cus').append('<tr id="high"><td style="display:none;">' + element.customerId + '</td>' +
                            '<td> ' + element.customerName + '</td > ' +
                            '<td>' + element.customerTelephone + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + element.customerAddress + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + element.customerEmail + '</td>'
                        );
                    });
                    cus = data;

                }
            });
        }
        var rowid;
        function getrow() {
            var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
            var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
            tbody.onclick = function (e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                var data = [];
                var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
                while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
                    target = target.parentNode;
                }
                if (target) {
                    var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");
                    data.push(cells[0].innerHTML);
                }

                rowid = data
            };
        }

        function addCustomer() {
            uri = 'https://localhost:44336/api/customer';
            var itemObj = {
                'CustomerName': $('#add-name').val(),
                'CustomerTelephone': $('#add-telephone').val(),
                'CustomerAddress': $('#add-address').val(),
                'CustomerEmail': $('#add-email').val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: uri,
                data: JSON.stringify(itemObj),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    getCustomer();
                    $('#add-name').val('');
                    $('#add-telephone').val('');
                    $('#add-address').val('');
                    $('#add-email').val('');
                }
            });
        }

        function deleteItem(rowid) {
            uri = 'https://localhost:44336/api/customer';
            $.ajax({
                url: uri + '/' + rowid,
                type: 'DELETE',
                success: function (result) {
                    getCustomer()
                }
            });

        }

        function editItem(rowid) {
            $.each(cus, function (key, item) {
                if (item.customerId == rowid) {
                    $('#edit-id').val(item.customerId);
                    $('#edit-name').val(item.customerName);
                    $('#edit-telephone').val(item.customerTelephone);
                    $('#edit-address').val(item.customerAddress);
                    $('#edit-email').val(item.customerEmail);
                }
            });
        }

        function editcustomer() {
            $("#spoilertwo").show();
            const item = {
                'customerName': $('#edit-name').val(),
                'customerTelephone': $('#edit-telephone').val(),
                'customerAddress': $('#edit-address').val(),
                'customerEmail': $('#edit-email').val()

            };

            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://localhost:44336/api/customer/' + rowid,
                type: 'PUT',
                accepts: 'application/json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(item),
                success: function (result) {
                    getCustomer();
                    $('#edit-name').val('');
                    $('#edit-telephone').val('');
                    $('#edit-address').val('');
                    $('#edit-email').val('');
                }
            });

            $("#spoiler").hide();

            return false;
        };

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you have tried? Check [Add paging functionality to the Students Index page
](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.2#add-paging-functionality-to-the-students-index-page) for server side pagination.

Comment: The resource you have linked is for a razor page web application not web api.

Comment: The key point is `PaginatedList`, it is not related with razor or web api.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the matter, i'm quite new to this.

Comment: What have you tried and what is your current code?

Comment: I added my code